# Run Macro When Cell Programatically Changes

Tags: excel, cell

I filter data into excel from an external financial software. It operates in real time and I want it when say cell B4 changes programatically by the real time financial software that Macro 1 will run. A few issues to be aware of are, the real time data may change in milliseconds.

If this is impossible then as a back up I would like to be able to copy and paste that Cell B4 every time it changes to say B10 then once it changes again put the new value in B10 and have the old value in B10 shift down to B11, then when B4 changes again have that value copied into B10 and shift down the previous two values so that the newest data is always in B10.

Answer (score 3):

Setup an onWorksheet_Change event, this should run everytime the worksheet changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$4" Then

    'Place appropriate code here

    End If
End Sub
```

I don't know what would occur if another update occurred while this was running though.

Answer (score 0):

If your cell value change every milisecond, you may have performance issues (or loops) with a vba event macro like Craig T showed.

You should probably add some checks on the update frequency and if you need to disable vba event, use :

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
' Coding to skip these events
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Regards,

Max